# LINQ: Set a default value if navigation property is null

Tags: c#, linq

This is my current LINQ statement:

```
var results = from l in leads
    select new MyObject
    {
        LeadID = l.LeadID,
        SelectedProposalEngineerID = l.LeadContacts.Where(contact => contact.LeadContactTypeID == LeadContactType.ProposalEngineer).FirstOrDefault().ContactID
    };
```

The trouble I'm having is that the last item is often null.  So when I try to convert "results" to a List, I get

> {"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."}

I don't want to make SelectedProposalEngineerID  a nullable int, for problems that would cause down stream.  How would I give it a value of 0 when it's null?

I have seen a LOT of other threads about this, but I can't seem to adapt any of their answers to this case.

Comment: Two clarifications - (1) are you sure the exception is related to SelectedProposalEngineerID? (2) what do you mean by "the last item" (which is often null)? A lead, a contact, or the FirstOrDefault() on selected contacts?

Comment: Good questions.  Let me get back to you in a minute after I look into this

Comment: Ok, so there are not always rows in the LeadContact table where LeadContact.LeadId is equal to the Lead.LeadId

Comment: @Fabio's answer is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method.

```
var results = from l in leads
    select new MyObject
    {
        LeadID = l.LeadID,
        SelectedProposalEngineerID = 
            l.LeadContacts.Where(contact => contact.LeadContactTypeID == LeadContactType.ProposalEngineer)
                          .Select(contact => contact.ContactID)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                          .FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Nullable<int> ID;
var results = from l in leads
select new MyObject
{
    LeadID = l.LeadID,
    SelectedProposalEngineerID = (ID = l.LeadContacts.Where(contact => contact.LeadContactTypeID == LeadContactType.ProposalEngineer).FirstOrDefault().ContactID).HasValue ? ID.Value : 0;
};
```

A ternary operator should do the job. Assign the result to a variable, then if it's not null, cast the variable to `int` and return it, else return 0.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that.  I get: Operator ?? can not be applied to types of int and int?

Comment: Edited my answer simply for correctness, @Fabio's answer is the way to go.